# Controller with related data - Entity Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I try show in my view information with few related tables. I'd like to show items from 'uzytkownik' after choose from 'przedmioty' data.
I have models:

```
'przedmioty' ['idPrzedmiot']
'rolaPowWykladowca' ['idRolaPowWykladowca', 'idUzytkownik', 'idPrzedmiot', (...)]
'uzytkownik' ['idUzytkownik',(...)]
```

I tried to do my controller as Instructor Controller here https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I created ViewModel :

```
public class PrzedmiotViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<przedmioty> Przedmioty { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<przedmiotPowWykladowca> PrzedmiotPowWykladowca { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<uzytkownik> Uzytkownik { get; set; }
}
```

And now my controller looks like:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? PrzedmiotID, int? UzytkownikID, int? FormaZajecId)
    {
        var viewModel = new PrzedmiotViewModel();
        viewModel.Przedmioty = db.przedmioty;

        if (UzytkownikID != null)
        {
            ViewBag.idUzytkownik = UzytkownikID.Value;
            viewModel.Uzytkownik = viewModel.PrzedmiotPowWykladowca
                .Where(x => x.idUzytkownik == UzytkownikID).SingleOrDefault().uzytkownik;
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The error is:

> Cannot imlicitly convert type 'Aplikacja.Models.uzytkownik' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Aplikacja.Models.uzytkownik>'. An explicit conversion exist (are you missing a cast?)

I also tried in this way:

```
        if (PrzedmiotID != null)
        {
            ViewBag.idPrzedmiot = PrzedmiotID.Value;

            viewModel.Uzytkownik = (from p in viewModel.Przedmioty
                                    where p.idPrzedmiot == PrzedmiotID
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        przedmioty = p,
                                        przedmiotPowWykladowca = (from pw in p.przedmiotPowWykladowca
                                                                  where pw.idPrzedmiot == PrzedmiotID
                                                                  select new
                                                                  {
                                                                      przedmiotPowWykladowca = pw,
                                                                      uzytkownik = from u in pw.idUzytkownik == u.idUzytkownik  
                                                                                   select u
                                                                  })
                                    }).Single().uzytkownik;
        }
```

But there

> u (in u.idUzytkownik) does not exist in the curent context

I think in good way or my ideas are generally wrong?

---EDIT---

```
        if (PrzedmiotID != null)
        {
            ViewBag.idPrzedmiot = PrzedmiotID.Value;
            var selectedPrzedmiotPowWykladowca = viewModel.PrzedmiotPowWykladowca
            .Where(x => x.idPrzedmiot == PrzedmiotID).ToList();

            db.Entry(selectedPrzedmiotPowWykladowca).Collection(x => x.uzytkownik).Load();
            foreach (uzytkownik uzytkownik in selectedPrzedmiotPowWykladowca.uzytkownik)
            {
                db.Entry(uzytkownik).Reference(x => x.rola).Load();
            }

            viewModel.Uzytkownik = selectedPrzedmiotPowWykladowca.uzytkownik;
        }
```

I did something like this, but there's still an error:

> Error CS1061  'List' does not contain a definition for 'uzytkownik' and no extension method 'uzytkownik' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

--EDIT--

```
        if (PrzedmiotID != null)
        {
            ViewBag.idPrzedmiot = PrzedmiotID.Value;

            var viewUzytkownik = new PrzedmiotViewModel();
            viewUzytkownik.PrzedmiotPowWykladowca = db.przedmiotPowWykladowca.Where(x => x.idPrzedmiot == PrzedmiotID)
                .Include(x => x.uzytkownik);

            return View(viewUzytkownik);
```

And this is the view to this part:

```
@foreach (var przedmioty in Model.Przedmioty)
{
    @foreach (var uzytkownik in Model.Uzytkownik)
    {
        string selectedRow = "";
        if (przedmioty.idPrzedmiot == ViewBag.idPrzedmiot)
        {
            selectedRow = "selectedrow";
        }
        <tr clss="@selectedRow">
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Wybierz", "Index", new { idUzytkownik = uzytkownik.idUzytkownik })
            </td>
            <td>
                @uzytkownik.imie
            </td>
            <td>
                @uzytkownik.nazwisko
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

There isn't error, but it don't work - I mean in my view after select 'przedmioty' view doesn't show records from 'uzytkownik'(idPrzedmiot is shoosen after select). Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Your Uzytkownik  property on the VM is a collection and in your controller you are setting it to a SingleorDefault? Thats what wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did linq query like there:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? PrzedmiotID)
    {
        if (PrzedmiotID == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var wykladowcy = from p in db.przedmioty
                         join ppw in db.przedmiotPowWykladowca on p.idPrzedmiot equals ppw.idPrzedmiot
                         join f in db.formaZajec on ppw.idFormaZajec equals f.idFormaZajec
                         join u in db.uzytkownik on ppw.idUzytkownik equals u.idUzytkownik                            
                         where ppw.idPrzedmiot == PrzedmiotID.Value
                         select new PrzedmiotViewModel { Przedmioty = p, PrzedmiotPowWykladowca = ppw, Uzytkownik = u, FormaZajec = f};
        if (wykladowcy == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(wykladowcy);
    }
```

I changed view model to this:

```
public class PrzedmiotViewModel
{
    public przedmioty Przedmioty { get; set; }
    public przedmiotPowWykladowca PrzedmiotPowWykladowca { get; set; }
    public uzytkownik Uzytkownik { get; set; }
    public formaZajec FormaZajec { get; set; }
}
```

And in the view I add:

```
@model IEnumerable<Aplikacja.ViewModels.PrzedmiotViewModel>
```

Hope if anyone have got similar problem it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible error causes. Either Uzytkownik property is of type 'Aplikacja.Models.uzytkownik' or your model declaration in view is of type 'Aplikacja.Models.uzytkownik'. Just look at exception stacktrace for more details.

Comment: There's still an error, I tried to fix it as you said but I'm not able to do this.

Comment: I changed code in controller that in my opinion should work (I edited question) if you could take a look on it I would be grateful